# Properly setting up a Project using the MVVM pattern

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

### Introduction

I know this is a very basic question, but I've spent quite some time reading or watching online tutorials, but I simply can't fully grasp how to properly implement a MVVM pattern in my project. I know how to set up a WPF Project using MVVM, but I don't know when and where I should use it.

### Problem

I am currently tasked to set up a WPF Project. Since I never worked with WPF before and had a lot of issues with my bindings - due to not understanding MVVM -  I made the mistake of trying to solve most of my problems in code-behind, ignoring the XAML file as good as I could. This backfired ever since and I'd like  to rework my code. However, before I can start I need to understand why my Bindings won't work and how to fix it.

My current Project consists of:

- 1 main UserControl using MVVM which displays 4 panels
- 4 UserControls as Children of my main control without MVVM. One for each panel
- 2 Windows without MVVM created from my main Control
- a Couple of extra classed with helpers and some other stuf

I originially only split up my main user Control, because my c# code to calculate the content of my panels grew quite large and I thought this might help to keep my project more clear, but since i couldn't get the bindings to work in my sub-controls, I simpy set them in my code behind instead of using xaml. I've seen other projects with a single MVVM UserControl, which contains thousands of lines of code behind, while its child contols contain some events at best. Is this how it is supposed to be?

### My Questions

- What needs a ViewModel? Do I need a ViewModel for my Child Controls? Do I need a ViewModel for my Windows? When do I need a ViewModel, when not?
- What belongs where? Is it generally wrong to write C# Code in Child Controls without ViewModel? What is the best way to keep my code small?
- How to bind? I can bind DependencyProperties in my Child Controls, but creating a DependencyProperty in my main Control for something that's only used in a Child Controls seems redundant. How do I set my DataContext for Child Controls?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Too broad and opinion-based. However *"Is it generally wrong to write C# Code in Child Controls without ViewModel?"* - no, quite the opposite. It is generally wrong that controls have own view models. They should only expose dependency properties, and handle their internal state logic in their code behind.

Comment: So every single Property in my controls should be a dependency property, even if I don't want to bind it from my parent control?

Comment: Usually yes. If you're absolutely sure you'll never need to bind a property (or animate it or set it by style etc.) you may as well use a regular C# property.

Comment: Too broad, this will probably be closed. I would recommend you buy/steal the books "Pro WPF and Silverlight MVVM" (Gary McLean Hall) and "Advanced MVVM" (Josh Smith). Basically you do as much of the actual display logic as you can in the view model and you very loosely bind to it in the view. A proper MVVM application will require no code-behind whatsoever and very few (if any) custom UserControls. Also beware of overuse of converters and behaviours, it's often a good sign that your view model isn't providing data in a format your view can conveniently consume.

Comment: That said, kudos to you for at least trying to go down the MVVM route. There's a light-bulb moment where you suddenly "get" what MVVM is, and after that it all becomes much easier. Basically your view model *is* where the majority of your GUI resides, the views simply display your view model on-screen and direct input commands back. A well architectured MVVM app will allow you to run the entire application with no view objects at all using other code to inject the commands that you would normally be receiving from the view.

Comment: I still miss something to get my bindings to work. I have a DataGrid which i want to bind to a list (lDataModelList) containing objects of a DataModel class with 4 Properties I created. I made the list a dependency property and bound the ItemsSource of my Grid to the list ( <DataGrid Name ="MyDataGrid" Itemssource="{Binding lDataModelList}">), but the Grid stays empty. Setting the ItemsSource (like MyDataGrid.ItemsSource = lDataModelList) in Code behind would work, however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this [Tutorial](https://blog.scottlogic.com/2012/02/06/a-simple-pattern-for-creating-re-useable-usercontrols-in-wpf-silverlight.html) comes closest on what i was looking for.

It explains most of my problems regarding Bindings and is a solid base for me to work on.

I don't know if I am supposed to post this as an answer, but since most of my issues are addressed by now, I wanted to close this question.